# Fat model in Rails: How do I return hash (errors) or object (when success)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Order model, and I'm trying to move the business logic into Order instead of OrderController. Here's the problem I'm facing:

```
class Api::V1::OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:create, :show, :index]
  respond_to :json
  def create
    order = current_retailer.orders.build
    order.checkout_cash(current_retailer, params[:order][:product_ids_with_quantities], order_params[:member_external_id])

    puts order
    if order.key?(:errors)
      render json: order, status: 422
    else
      render json: order, status: 201
    end
    puts "HEY!!!"
    puts order.inspect

end
```

so the `order.checkout_cash` method is the business logic I'm implementing in Order model.

I have to know if it's a valid or it returns an error.

Here's my code in Order model:

```
  def checkout_cash(current_retailer, product_ids_with_quantities, member_external_id)
    puts "CASH!!!"
    order = current_retailer.orders.build
    order.payment_method = "cash"
    order.build_placements(product_ids_with_quantities)
    order.set_total_charge!
    if member_external_id.blank?
      return order
    else
      member = Member.find_by(member_external_id: external_id)
      if member
        order.add_points(member)
        return order
      else
        return {errors: "Not a member or wrong membership id. Please register first"}
      end
    end
```

In OrderController the line

```
if order.key?(:
```

results in:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `key?' for #<Order:0x007fb7a29ec260>
```

I'm sure it's because I'm calling a function on hash, on a Order object. How should I do this in Rails?

---

Now:

```
def create
  order = current_retailer.orders.build
  checkout_result = order.checkout_cash(current_retailer, params[:order][:product_ids_with_quantities], order_params[:member_external_id])

  puts order

  if checkout_result.key?(:errors)
    render json: order, status: 422
  else
    order.save!
    order.reload
    render json: order, status: 201
  end
```

is getting:

```
1) Api::V1::OrdersController POST #create create with default total_charge return 0 as total_charge
  Failure/Error: get :create, retailer_id: @retailer, order: {product_ids_with_quantities: []}
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `key?' for #<Order:0x007ff69244fb70>
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  # ./app/controllers/api/v1/orders_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:629:in `process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:65:in `process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
  # /opt/twitter/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:505:in `get'
  # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/orders_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Could you add the whole code for your `Order` model? It looks like you have no method named `key?` in the `Order` model.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Thanks for the reply!. That's true. Order doesn't have key. The question at hand is how to distinguish between an hash (which means error in the logic) and an object (which means a success build for order)

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: It looks like your update is missing some information, which object raised the `NoMethodError`?

Comment: So sorry. Updated again. @mrodrigues

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't necessary to put "updated" in your question when you make a change. Just put the information where it's necessary so the question makes sense. We can tell when you've made a change because Stack Overflow maintains a revision history. If you feel it's really necessary to mark a section as being different, use `---` to add a horizontal rule to the question. Also, please take the time to read the documentation for [formatting a question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It helps us to help you if we can read it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the `checkout_cash` return value. The correct code should be:

```
checkout_result = order.checkout_cash(current_retailer, params[:order][:product_ids_with_quantities], order_params[:member_external_id])

if checkout_result.key?(:errors)
  render json: order, status: 422
else
  render json: order, status: 201
end
```

UPDATE:

I misread the `checkout_cash` method. I'd advise you against allowing a method to return different classes depending on the input, it forces the caller to know the method's internal behaviour. Since you're not using the `order` object which inside `checkout_cash`, you could simply return a empty hash in case of success.

However, I think this method has too many responsibilities that don't concern to the `Order` class. You could write a form object to handle this custom validation and keep your model simple. Check this great article: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/.

Comment: Ok now I changed to as suggested. Please see the update

Comment: Looks like it's an order object... still the same problem, but thanks for making it closer!